# Export RAT (KEA driver) to Shapefile

Tags: raster, shapefile, convert, attribute-table, raster-attribute-table

I have a dataset of rasters (driver [kea](http://www.kealib.org/)) whose has, let's say, 20-30 attributes in their RAT. I'm realizing how to have these attributes in shapefiles (without using proprietary software). I've read a lot of stuff in GDAL and Python, but I was not able to solve it. Since I can't convert my rasters to shapefiles via gdal_polygonize.py (It doesn't deal with RATs), I'm trying to find and alternative to convert the RATs to CSV or any format that allows me to do a join, after all.

I'm failing to identify a proper solution. Could anyone point me some clue? How can I convert rasters (kea format, in this case) to shape so that I can have the entire attribute table? Or can I export the RAT so that I can join it to a shapefile?

**EDIT**

Recently I made a progress. I'm able to store the column names (and eventually column values in python. But how to export/save them in a manageable format (cvs,txt,ascii) is still lacking solution.

```
>#!/usr/bin/env python 
># Import python modules 
>from rsgislib import rastergis 
>from osgeo import gdal 
># The output segments (clumps) image 
>seg = "cur_segs_50_1000_UTM.kea" 
>outfile = "test.txt" 
>img= gdal.Open(seg) 
>band=img.GetRasterBand(1) 
>rat=band.GetDefaultRAT() 
>icolcount=rat.GetColumnCount() 
>cols=[] 
>for icol in range(icolcount): 
>cols.append(rat.GetNameOfCol(icol))
```

Comment: Recently I made a progress. I'm able to store the column names (and eventually column values in python. But how to export/save them in a manageable format (cvs,txt,ascii) is still lacking solution. >#!/usr/bin/env python

># Import python modules
>from rsgislib import rastergis
>from osgeo import gdal

># The output segments (clumps) image
>seg = "cur_segs_50_1000_UTM.kea"
>outfile = "test.txt"

>img= gdal.Open(seg)
>band=img.GetRasterBand(1)

>rat=band.GetDefaultRAT()

>icolcount=rat.GetColumnCount()
>cols=[]
>for icol in range(icolcount):
   >cols.append(rat.GetNameOfCol(icol))`

Comment: If you have RSGISLib installed why don't you use the rastergis.export2Ascii function? (http://rsgislib.org/rsgislib_rastergis.html#rsgislib.rastergis.export2Ascii)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the rios (raster input/output simplification) module to read the columns of the RAT, giving you a numpy array which can be written to a csv

```
col_names = rios.rat.getColumnNames(img)
rat_values = []
for col in col_names:
    rat_values.append(rios.rat.readCoumn(img, col)
```

Alternatively it will possibly be easier to create a gdal image directly from the RAT:

```
rsgislib.rastergis.exportCols2GDALImage
```

Allowing you to use gdal_polygonize.py, see here for the docs: http://www.rsgislib.org/rsgislib_rastergis.html